# header location not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know what's going in laravel. It doesn't work using the Header location in php.

```
$d = "http://www.google.com";
header('Location: '.$d);
```

and if I use **Redirect::to()** in my local, nothing happen. Is there something I need to setup first in laravel 5.2?

Comment: Do you do just `Redirect::to('someurl')` or do you actually do `return Redirect::to('someurl')`?

Comment: Are you making Ajax call to the function where you have written code for redirection?

Comment: @JoelHinz i didn't use the return

Comment: @AshuJha nope. just pure php

Comment: So use the return then like you should? :)

Comment: @JoelHinz you are right. why is it the header() doesn't work in laravel? it is pure php.

Comment: It's because Laravel has its own way of attaching headers to responses: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Laravel 5.2**. You **should** do like this

```
redirect()->to('url')->send();
```

**Or**

```
return redirect()->to('url');
```

Comment: thanks for this. I dont have any idea that return is useful in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Check for this method:

```
return redirect()->to('url');
```

Comment: This is already mentioned in [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39163580).